# JPG corrupted after passing through AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently in the process  of moving a web-service behind an AWS API gateway, and I'm running into trouble with jpeg uploads.

The gateway at this point is a mere proxy. There's an ANY resource that just proxies everything to the service with the same path (right now it's mostly just intended to provide https support on an old url while the service moves domains). The content handling of the proxy is set to passthrough, so it shouldn't be re-encoding anything.

But when I now upload a jpg in a form-data request, the uploaded images are there, but cannot  be opened. When trying to open them I get the error:
`Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf`

Now I now what you're thinking, you want to tell me that my jpg is actually a png. Believe me, it isn't. The pipeline delivering these images has worked reliably for *years*, I can  open the jpgs before I upload them, and also I cannot open the files on the server if I rename them to .png. Somehow, the API gateway seems to corrupt the form-data passing through.

So I've done some Hexing with an image before and after passing through the gateway. The contents are identical, except for the first bytes in the file. Before the image passes through the gateway, the beginning of the file looks like this:

`FF D8 FF E1 FF FE`

After the upload, this is replaced with:

`EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD`

Otherwise the files are identical. Why would the gateway be doing that, and how do I stop it? (according to the gateway logs, the content-type header of the incoming request *is* image/jpeg, so there shouldn't be issues with that either...)

Comment: Maybe they are in base64. Have you tried decoding them?

Comment: I've added some more information. It's definitely binary, but for some reason the file header seems to get replaced.

Comment: How did you integrate API gateway? To S3? Is it direct integration, or you are uploading through lambda?

Comment: The image is sent by a lambda to the gateway, which then proxies the request to an elastic beanstalk application. If the image is sent from the lambda directly to the application, everything is fine. When proxied through the gateway, the fileheaders are replaced.

Comment: API gateway have setting for [binary content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html). Did you set it it up for your uploaded?

Comment: That would be the content-handling, I assume? It's set to always pass through. As I understand it, this is used to convert between base64 and binary. Most of the requests are json, only some contain binary data. I could single out the methods receiving binary and change their content-handling, but in that case they would just use passthrough when they're getting binary, which is what they'll be getting, so I don't think that would make any difference.

Comment: Ok, no, you meant the *binary media types* in the API settings, which I didn't know were around until I read what was written in your link. Once I added image/jpeg and multipart/form-data to the list there, it worked! So thaaaaaanks a whole damn lot. If you want you can formulate a proper answer, otherwise  I'll do it myself in a while.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it worked out. I will post an answer:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by not setting up [Binary Media Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) in API gateway:

> In API Gateway, the API request and response have a text or **binary payload**. A text payload is a UTF-8-encoded JSON string. A binary payload is anything other than a text payload. The binary payload can be, for example, a **JPEG file**, a GZip file, or an XML file.

For [AWS Lambda proxy integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html):

> you must base64-encode your function's response. You **must also configure the binaryMediaTypes** for your API.